# Loading Spring Application Context in a Java SE application

Tags: java, spring, desktop-application, spring-data-jpa, applicationcontext

We have a multi user Java SE (desktop, Swing based) application which uses Spring Data JPA. The Spring Application context is loaded using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and the application works perfectly fine for a single user. When multiple users logon to the application Application Context is created for each user.

Loading the Application Context multiple times is utilizing more CPU which is causing the application performance to degrade. The application is designed in such a way that each user gets their own instance which makes it harder to share Application Context.

Is there a way to centralize Application context to be loaded only once irrespective of the user signing in to the application.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How swing app being used by multiple user at the same time ? They share the same PC ? same Keyboard ?

Comment: Put your App on server and consume a REST API for multiple Swing based Clients.